# Folding doesn't work for C/C++

Tags: syntax-highlighting, folding, filetype-c++, filetype-c

I've been having a ridiculously hard time getting C/C++ code folding to work with `set foldmethod=syntax`. To debug my issue I've stripped down my vimrc to **only** this:

```
set foldmethod=syntax
syntax on                " also tried putting this first
```

Now when I open a cpp file, nothing is folded.

Then, doing `:syntax off` followed by `:syntax on` *will* fold the cpp file.

Any idea why that does something not already done by the trivial vimrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some detective work I tracked down the cause of my issue being that I had a `.vim` file in my plugin directory that redefined `OperatorChars`, which broke the `syntax` based folding for C and C++.